# Opencv Colour detection C++

Tags: c++, debugging, opencv, visual-studio-2013, youtube

I watched a video on youtube on colour tracking with contour lines, link is followed below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQ-bpfdWQh8

The source code is available for download at the comment section.

There are errors at line 220 about cannythreshold, but i deleted it.
Another error is at line 234, the track filtered object part, I don't know what should i add in since it is asking for 1 more argument
What should i do to make this code work?

Comment: you can at least post the line that gives you the error (a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be better), with the error you're having.

Comment: http://akaifi.github.io/MultiObjectTrackingBasedOnColor/

Comment: trackFilteredObject(threshold, HSV, cameraFeed); this is said that too few argument . it is in the int main function, all the libraries are included. this is the only line of error left